# How to extract Hyperlink address from webpage

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

So I want to extract specific hyperlink addresses from this webpage: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012%E2%80%9313_NBA_season

that match a certain pattern.

I tried this bit of code here:

```
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012%E2%80%9313_NBA_season"
webpage <- read_html(url)
links <- webpage %>% html_nodes("a[href*= wiki ]") %>% html_text() 
links
```

But only got the hyperlinked word or phrase instead of the link itself.
The result that I am looking for would be the Hyperlink web address as a character string but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Not the text but the attribute that defines where the links leads to:

```
links <- webpage %>% html_nodes("a[href*= wiki ]") %>% html_attr('href')
```

Comment: Thank you. This got exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

this code i m giving will work in python and it will show all the hyperlinks in result

```
import csv  # file operations
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # lib for pulling data from html/xmlsites
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  # lib for sending and rec info over http
Url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012%E2%80%9313_NBA_season'
pageHtml = uReq(Url)
soup = soup(pageHtml,"html.parser") #parse the html
li = soup.find_all("li")
print(li)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider doing it in python, it can help you get all the hyperlink.

```
li = soup.find_all("a")
for link in li:
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print (link.attrs['href'])
```